# How too add typing to webpack external

Tags: typescript

I have following configuration in webpack;

```
externals: {
  config:{
    url: '',
    key: ''
  }
}
```

I want to use this config, in ts files.

```
import {url} from 'config';
```

How can I add type to config, so I wont get error, and will get type compilation from browser?

(asking content for `type.d.ts` file, currently looks like this)

```
declare module 'config' {
  // something
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simpler than I thought,

```
declare module 'config' {
  export const url: string;
}
```